# Why am I not loosing weight doing intermittent fasting?

Tags: ketogenic-diet, intermittent-fasting

My height is 172 cm, my weight is hovering about 77kg to 75kg. My goal weight is 71kg and I got close to that weight by doing 48 hours IT without eating, during the week I practice 24 hour IT every day. I notice that the weight is stubbornly stuck at 77kg to 75kg every week and does not seem to go anywhere.

I am mildly active, I walk / run every other day and I do squats and push ups once or twice a week with rope jumping thrown in. My diet is keto most of the time. I eat once a day. What can I do to get out of this rut ?

Answer (score 1):

Give your body a break. Increase your calories for a week or two, then reduce them about ten to 20 percent a day. Your body will get out of starvation mode and you will slowly start losing again. Worst thing to do is panic when the weight goes up and return to your body punishing routine.